# Convert to text truncating leading zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using `=TEXT()` function in Excel to convert alphanumeric to a string. All of them convert except part numbers that have a leading zero, e.g. 012345.

Currently my function is `=TEXT(Input!B10, "0")`. I have tried different variations of this without success. I have searched the Interwebs for an answer, also without success. Everything converts to a string EXCEPT for numbers with ONE leading zero. I have even setup a new workbook to test, and I get the same result. This is part of a larger macro to get custom prices for my ERP system.

Comment: So what would the value in say Input!B10 look like that causes the issue? I am confused at the moment because would an alphanumeric not already be a string?

Comment: Alphanumeric is already a string, so no conversion is necessary. Your question is confusing, because there is no conversion needed from an alphanumeric (string) to a string. Can you edit to explain what you're actually asking?

Comment: As a test, put 012345 in a cell. Change the cell to Text. Now use the function to return that string in another cell. Mine always returns 12345.

Comment: Do you want to return `012345`?  That is not what you are trying to return with the TEXT.

Comment: That is correct. Because it converts to value. `=TEXT(Input!B10,"000000")` would return with the zero.

Comment: Do you want to return a number that has at least six numbers?

Comment: @ everyone. I have a LIST of alphanumerical characters e.g. part numbers. The length of each is variable. Like I said before all of part numbers format correctly except the ones with a leading 0. If it has leading 00 it converts fine. I cannot find any reference that deals with this.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically you can just do this. This would assume you have 0123456 in `B10` formatted as Text. It will format to keep the same amount of leading zeros as in the original.

```
=TEXT(B10,REPT(0,LEN(B10)))
```

Answer (score -1):

## The TYPE Worksheet Function

> ```
> =IF(TYPE(INPUT!B10)=2,B10,TEXT(INPUT!B10,"#"))
> ```

If you don't want to show other text values use this:

```
=IF(TYPE(B10)=2,IF(LEFT(B10,1)="0",B10,""),TEXT(B10,"#"))
```

If you want to convert empty cells to 0 then use:

```
=IF(TYPE(INPUT!B10)=2,B10,TEXT(INPUT!B10,0))
```

### VBA Help

**Type**

Returns the type of value. Use TYPE when the behavior of another function depends on the type of value in a particular cell.

**Syntax**
TYPE(value)

'Value' can be any Microsoft Excel value, such as a number, text, logical value, and so on.

```
If value is   TYPE returns 
Number             1 
Text               2 
Logical value      4 
Error value       16 
Array             64
```